# shared preferences problem

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am having a problem putting a variable to shared preferences. I am getting a contacts id,name and number from the contact picker then saving them to a shared preference so that i can use them in another activity to put in a database but every time i go to get them in that other activity it gives me the phone number when i ask for the name or id??

ie. contact info activity

```
id "displays the id"
name "displays name"
phone "displays phone"
```

second activity

```
id "displays phone number"
name "displays phone number"
phone "displays phone number"
```

i dont get it?

here is my code

preference class

```
public class SmsPrefs extends PreferenceActivity {

public static final String ID = "";
public static final String NAME = "";
public static final String NUMBER = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.sms_pref);
}
```

}

getting contact info snippet

```
    public void getContactData(Intent data){
    Context context = this;

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Uri contactData = data.getData();
    Log.v("Contact", contactData.toString());
    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData,null,null,null,null);

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
            id = contactData.getLastPathSegment();
            editor.putString(SmsPrefs.ID, id);
            editor.commit();
        Log.v("Contact", "ID: " + id.toString());
            name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            editor.putString(SmsPrefs.NAME, name);
            editor.commit();
        Log.v("Contact", "Name: " + name.toString());

        if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                if(pCur.moveToFirst()){
              phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
              editor.putString(SmsPrefs.NUMBER, phone);
              editor.commit();
              Log.v("Contact", "Phone Number: " + phone.toString());
                }
          pCur.close();
      }
    }
    c.close();
}
```

if i get the 3 values from shared preferences while still in this activity i get the correct values

second activity snippet

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name = new String ("name");
            String id = new String ("id");
            String phone = new String ("number");

            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(v.getContext());

            id = pref.getString(SmsPrefs.ID, "");
            name = pref.getString(SmsPrefs.NAME, "");
            phone = pref.getString(SmsPrefs.NUMBER, "");

            Log.v("EditContact", "ID: " + id);
            Log.v("EditContact", "Name: " + name);
            Log.v("EditContact", "Phone: " + phone);

            db.open();
            db.deleteContact(7);
            db.close();

            db.open();
            long _id;
            _id = db.insertContact(phone, name, nColor, nVibrate, ringTonePath);
            db.close();
            Log.v("EditContact", "ID: " + _id);
            Intent ok = new Intent(EditContact.this,Contacts.class);
            startActivity(ok);
        }
    });
```

i dont understand how it is changing when those are the only 2 times i use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your `SmsPrefs.ID`, `.NAME` and `.NUMBER` are the same value. They need to be different or they will overwrite each other.

You can:

- Change the order in which you write the data, writing the phone number before the name and id. This should alter your results and confirm the problem.
- Step through the app in the debugger to see what the actual values of those constants are
- Post your `SmsPrefs` code for us to investigate.

Try changing your `SmsPrefs` constants to:

```
public static final String ID = "com.example.SmsPrefs.ID";
public static final String NAME = "com.example.SmsPrefs.NAME";
public static final String NUMBER = "com.example.SmsPrefs.NUMBER";
```

Your keys actually have to be different from one another.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put up my smsprefs but its up there now

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String ID = "";
public static final String NAME = "";
public static final String NUMBER = "";
```

Those need to be set to something like:

```
public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String NAME = "_name";
public static final String NUMBER = "_number";
```